# When to use singular or plural of nouns

Tags: word-choice, nouns, grammatical-number

I'm not sure which to use of these to use:

The art of extracting onion from salad.

The art of extracting onion from a salad.

The art of extracting onions from salad.

The art of extracting onions from a salad.

Comment: None of them seems to make sense, april. Would 'The practice of adding onion/s to [a] salad' be an acceptable alternative?

Comment: "The art of extracting onions from a salad" sounds the most natural to me as a native American English speaker.  Typically we refer to a chopped or diced onion as "onions" when it is added as an ingredient.  For example, when ordering a burger I would say, "I'd like a burger with no onions."  All of the above is just my opinion based on the usage that I commonly hear in the Northeast United States.

Comment: It definitely is an art. Onions in salad are gross and should be extracted with care in order to avoid onion-smelling fingers.

Comment: "onions" could refer to onion slices or rings. And if baby onions, or shallots were used in the salad, you might expect to find more than one!

Answer (score 1):

OP's example context is "peculiar", to say the least. But the underlying grammatical principle  is that singular and plural are both perfectly accepable...

> 1: [hamburger with **onion**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mustn%27t%20have%20understood%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22hamburger%20with%20onion%22&tbm=bks) *("[mass noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)" - about 1000 instances in Google Books)*
>    2: [hamburger with **onions**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mustn%27t%20have%20understood%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22hamburger%20with%20onions%22&tbm=bks) *("[count noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun)" - about 3000 instances)*

I can't really explain why most people use (2) in such contexts, since it's highly unlikely they're expecting two or more *actual whole onions* with their burger.

If you want to follow the herd, use the plural form. But that does mean you'll have to learn where it's *not* appropriate - for example...

> 3: [gammon with **pineapple**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mustn%27t%20have%20understood%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22gammon%20with%20pineapple%22&tbm=bks) *(421 instance)*
>    4: [gammon with **pineapples**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mustn%27t%20have%20understood%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22gammon%20with%20pineapples%22&tbm=bks) *(**No** written instances)*

My advice therefore would be to stick with the singular for all contexts where it's remotely feasible to treat the relevant noun as a mass noun. And you can check that by considering whether you could reasonably say *"I don't want **much ???**"*, instead of *"I don't want **many ???s**"*)

Comment: Thanks for this response, FumbleFingers! That last part is very helpful. 

As for my four options, the second one did seem the most off. I think that if I’m considering all salads, I should use 1, and if I want to talk about one salad I should use 4. I think a fifth option could be “The art of extracting onions from salads”, though that feels less satirical than I intend (I was going to tweet one of these statements).

Comment: @aprilspring: Well, I don't understand your context at all. If you don't want onion in your salad, just don't put it. If someone else has already prepared a salad using onions, the taste is going to be there even if you laboriously pick out every solid speck of onion you can see. But I have to say it's totally irrelevant whether you're talking about one salad or several, just as it is with ***burgers** and onion/s*.

Comment: I am certainly a hard one to get! When I make a salad you can bet there will be no onion in it, but recently I purchased a salad described as "Roasted baby beets on a bed of mixed greens, goat cheese and candied pecans". Naturally I was not expecting onions, yet there they were. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @aprilspring: It might also be worth noting that you usually *extract* some substance you want to isolate in a "purer" form. In your case I assume you're not planning to extract the onion for use elsewhere - you just want to *get rid of it*. So perhaps [extirpate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/extirpate) *(to remove or destroy totally; do away with; exterminate)* might be a better choice.

Comment: "with [N]" or with "with [N]s" is used where N is a mass/uncountable or countable noun respectively.  Ketchup is an uncountable noun, so its always "with ketchup."  Onion can be treated as a countable or uncountable noun, so either might be used.  (if something is cooked or sliced it might tend to become an uncountable/mass noun).